# Changing puppet module source

Tags: puppet

I checked Puppet's documentation but didn't find any suggestions about it. I have Puppet module for `Monit` - https://forge.puppetlabs.com/dhoppe/monit . It already has some predefined configurations for some services in `files` folder - https://github.com/dhoppe/puppet-monit/tree/master/files/common/etc/monit/conf.d . 
I want to add more, but not sure how to do it in the correct puppet way.

Is it ok to add new service configuration to local `puppet/module/monit/files/ folder? Will this folder be overwritten when update for module comes? Or maybe there is a better way for it?

PS. My services aren't public wide, so i can't make pull request to original `dhoppe-monit` repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull request is a good keyword.

If you cannot send your requirements upstream, you may wish to maintain a private fork/branch instead. And yes, you will be required to accomodate for upstream changes yourself to make sure that your additions keep working.

Apart from writing your own module from scratch, I don't really see another way to make this happen.