# Should I edit modules from forge.puppetllabs.com directly?

Tags: puppet

When you install a module from forge.puppetlabs.com, the module is installed in /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules. Let's say I have installed the puppetlabs ntp module but need to customize it. Do I edit the module's files in /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/ntp or should I copy the ntp directory into another directory (a dir in the modulepath of course) and hack it up there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This question bears similarity to [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255185/changing-puppet-module-source) (no duplicate though, I feel).

What you really want to do is "fork" (in github speak) the module and use your own version right in place of the upstream one. Ideally, your changes are in general fashion and configurable, so that other users can benefit from them if you open a pull request to get your enhancements upstream.

Comment: So do I need to git fork each module? Don't know what fork means specific to my question. Is there a doc for this?

Comment: Well you don't *need* to go the github route, but if you modify a module without sending your changes upstream, you will have to find a way of coping with new upstream releases. `git` is a good way of doing that, and github is a handy cloud solution to keep your data in a central location.